# When the cursor leaves the screen, the game doesn't end in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The link to my code in CodePen - http://codepen.io/PartTimeCoder/pen/RaMZop?editors=0010

The Javascript is below, in the increase function there is an if command that should prevent the user's mouse from leaving the screen, but it doesn't work. Also, right when the page loads it should start adding the score, but instead it only starts after a click. I don't see any reason for this to happen:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")

    var height = window.innerHeight
    var width = window.innerWidth

    var mouse = {};
    var hover;

    var redDots = 2;
    var score = 0;

    canvas.width = width
    canvas.height = height

    var circle_count = 10;
    var circles = [];

    var generate = function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < circle_count; i++) {
            circles.push(new circle());
        }
    }

    setInterval(generate, 100);

    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', mousePos, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('touch', mousePos, false);

    function mousePos(e) {
        mouse.x = e.pageX;
        mouse.y = e.pageY;
    }

    function circle() {
        this.speed = {
            x: 2.5 + Math.random() * 5,
            y: 2.5 + Math.random() * 5
        }

        this.location = {
            x: 0 - Math.random() * width,
            y: 0 - Math.random() * height
        }

        this.accel = {
            x: -1.5 + Math.random() * 3,
            y: -1.5 + Math.random() * 3
        }
        this.radius = 5 + Math.random() * 10
    }

    var draw = function() {
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "lighter";

        for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
            var c = circles[i];

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.fillStyle = "red";
            ctx.arc(c.location.x, c.location.y, c.radius, Math.PI * 2, false);
            ctx.fill();

            c.speed.x += c.accel.x;
            c.speed.y += c.accel.y;

            c.location.x += c.speed.x;
            c.location.y += c.speed.y;

            if (mouse.x > c.location.x - c.radius && mouse.x < c.location.x + c.radius && mouse.y > c.location.y - c.radius && mouse.y < c.location.y + c.radius) {
                hover = true;
            }

            if (hover) {
                $("canvas").hide();
                $("#message").html("Sorry you lost. You finished with a score of " + score + "!");
            }
        }
    }

    setInterval(draw, 33);

    var increase = function() {
        if (mouse.x > 1 && mouse.y > 1 && !hover) {
            score++;
            redDots += 25;
            $("#score").html("Score - " + score);
            console.log(redDots);
        }

        if (mouse.x > canvas.width || mouse.y > canvas.height || mouse.x < 0 || mouse.y < 0) {
            hover = true;
        }
    }

    setInterval(increase, 1000);
});
```

All help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would track that action by the `mouseleave` and `mouseenter` events

Comment: I don't get how to do that, that is my exact problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a `mouseout` event listener, simple!

But first, you need to track the mouse on the mousemove, to prevent starting the game by clicking first. I have an example below.

`canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', mousePos, false);`

Use that instead of the `mousedown` event listener.

Second, to fix the problem of stopping the game upon `mouseout`.
Here is an example

```
canvas.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
        $("canvas").hide();
        $("#message").html("Sorry you lost. You finished with a score of " + score + "!");
    }, false);
```

What this does is the same thing as when your mouse touches a red dot, but it will display the message upon your mouse leaving the canvas. There you go!

Here is an example codepen of the working version: [Avoid The Red Dots](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pyLWzz)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to track whether the mouse is in the document or not, and use that in your if statement as well. This code will track whether the mouse is in the document (or use a selector for your game-screen element if it's not the full height and width of the document):

```
var mouseIn = false;
$(document).on('mouseenter mouseover', function(){
    if(!mouseIn)mouseIn = true;
});
$(document).on('mouseleave', function(){
    if(mouseIn)mouseIn = false;
});
```

Then just check if `mouseIn` evaluates to `true` to see if the user's cursor is on the game-screen. Here's a fiddle demonstrating the `mouseIn` change: https://jsfiddle.net/sk23cssc/

Comment: I tried implementing that into my code, I either did it wrong or it didn't work.

Comment: Here is the updated version - http://codepen.io/PartTimeCoder/pen/RaMZop?editors=0010

Answer (score 0):

Add event listeners, instead of tracking mouse movement.

```
canvas.addEventListener('mouseout', mouseOutFunction, false);
```

This will run whatever function you provide for the second argument when the mouse leaves the screen.

If you want to start tracking score when the page loads, use the ready() function on the canvas

```
canvas.ready(pageLoadFunction);
```

This will run a function pageLoadFunction when canvas is finished loading

Comment: When I use the mouseout function, it just randomly ends the game at a certain time. Also the canvas.ready function didn't work either.